# Deploy Angular 2 Universal Starter to Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, universal

Has anyone downloaded the Angular 2 Universal Starter, executed "npm run build", that creates a client folder and a server folder, and then deployed it to Azure?

If so I really would like some pointers on how to proceed, because how hard I google there seams to be no one that have done it... :-)

Comment: You can get a hint from the post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. But I am not using the starter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577087/deploy-angular4-universal-app-in-azure-invalid-start-up-command