# Deploy Angular4 Universal app in Azure invalid start-up command

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, angular-universal

I have created a simple application with Angular 4.0.0 and Universal (platform-server) following [these steps](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal))

Basically it means that it's an Angular 4 application capable of being rendered in server side within a NodeJs environment.

Now I want to deploy this application to my Azure app services using Git and a command line so I followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs). Basically:

1. I [installed Azure-Cli 2.0 for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cli/azure/install-azure-cli#a-namemsi-for-the-windows-command-lineamsi-para-la-l%C3%ADnea-de-comandos-de-windows)
2. Open command line (cmd)
3. Run `az login`, it will ask to open a url and enter a code so that we can authenticate with it
4. Configure a deployment user with `az webapp deployment user set --user-name <myUser> --password <myPassword>`
5. Create resource group with `az group create --name myResourceGroup --location westeurope`
6. Create basic service plan with `az appservice plan create --name myServicePlan --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku B1`
7. Create web application with `az webapp create --name myApp --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myServicePlan`
8. Configure deployment with GIT with `az webapp deployment source config-local-git --name myUSer --resource-group myResourceGroup --query url --output tsv` and it returns `https://myUser@myApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/myApp.git`
9. Add an Azure remote to local git repository with `git remote add azure https://myUser@myApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/myApp.git`
10. Push to Azure remote to deploy app with `git push azure master`, it will prompt for the username and password set on step 4.

I got some errors saying that some dependencies were not available in npm. I noticed that the Azure nodeJs being used was old, so to enforce my Azure app services to use the same node version I am using locally (`node --version` is `v8.0.0` I added an `engines` section in my `package.json` like this:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.0.0"
  }
```

So now my `package.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc",
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.0.0"
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I run `git push azure master` to deploy in Azure I get an `invalid start-up command ts-node src/server.ts in package.json` so that **the application is in Azure but it fails to be deployed and doesn't run**. This is my output:

```
$ git push azure master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 344 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id 'd7229584fc'.
remote: Generating deployment script.
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling node.js deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Copying file: 'package.json'
remote: Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 8.0.0.
remote: Selected node.js version 8.0.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
remote: Selected npm version 5.0.0
remote: Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
remote: Invalid start-up command "ts-node src/server.ts" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".
remote: Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
remote: ......
remote: npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.28\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.0.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
remote: ........................................................
remote: added 17 packages in 73.406s
remote: Finished successfully.
remote: Running post deployment command(s)...
remote: Deployment successful.
To https://myApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/myApp.git
   d497e43..d722958  master -> master
```

It's the first time I attempt to deploy something in nodeJs and there are plenty of things I don't know yet about releasing for production an Angular app. What am I missing to make it work as it works locally when I run `npm start`?

Comment: About how to deploy an angular app to Azure Web App. you may check out [this blog post](https://prmadi.com/running-angular2-app-on-azure-app-services-with-ci-cd/) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJCIJZBMDmY) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's not what I am looking for. I need the angular app to render in server side (as a universal app) so I need somehow to run some command for node to start the server. This is what I haven't figured out yet. These examples are for standard client-side rendered angular apps.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am looking to do the same but can't figure out how to make it work. @iberodev

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an error for a malformed start command

```
remote: Invalid start-up command "ts-node src/server.ts" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".
```

[The documentation sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/blob/master/package.json) has `node` instead of `ts-node`